# PDO_Mysql adapter - data type comparison (identical comparison)

Tags: zend-framework, pdo, comparison

I have a few problem when I use PDO_Mysql adapter with Zend.

application.ini

```
resources.db.adapter = mysqli
resources.db.host = localhost
resources.db.dbname = myproject
resources.db.username = root
resources.db.password = 123456
resources.db.profiler.enabled = true
resources.db.profiler.class = "Zend_Db_Profiler_Firebug"
```

DB init in bootstrap.php

```
$database = $config['resources']['db'];
$db = Zend_Db::factory($database['adapter'], $database);
$db->setFetchMode(Zend_Db::FETCH_OBJ);
$db->query("SET NAMES 'utf8';");
$db->query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8';");

Zend_Db_Table::setDefaultAdapter($db);
Zend_Registry::getInstance()->set('db', $db);

return $db;
```

Ok, when I do a simple fetchAll() and check the loop:

```
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    if ($row->id === 1) {
        echo 'first id';
    } else {
        echo 'other rows';
    }
}
```

Exists a row in table with "ID" = "1" (integer), but, for any reason... when I use PDO_Mysql, I cant do data type comparison ("===" or "!=="), but if I use "Mysqli" adapter works fine.

With PDO_Mysql adapter, each column of each row are "string" (when I check with var_dump).

Somebody knows the reason ?

Thanks.

Comment: You could always simply convert the $row->id to an integer to do the comparison: intval($row->id) === 1 or the opposite: $row->id == '1'

Comment: Ok, yes... but... my question are about why in PDO_Mysql is impossible to do a simple identical comparison... only works fine with mysqli

Comment: Have you tried to change your Fetch Mode to something other then FETCH_OBJ, the integer may be cast as a string because of the way PDO implements the __toString for the FETCH_OBJ fetch Mode. besides if you know it's a string you can still compare as `=== '1'`, just sayin